# Can I get common hyperlinks in Info manuals?

Tags: man, info

If I view man pages using info (e.g. `info man`), I see common hyperlinks (e.g. `apropos(1)`).

However, Texinfo commands that create hyperlinks (e.g. `@xref`), in Info output, add a label (`*Note`) before the name of an hyperlink.

Concretely, `@xref{Node name}.` produces `*Note Node name::.` but I would like to get `Node name.` (without the inserted `*Note`).

How can I get common hyperlinks in Info manuals?

Comment: Sure - with an **`@anchor`**.  Gotta read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#toc-Cross_002dreferences), no cut/paste necessary...

Comment: @ThomasDickey \@anchor just provides a place for me to jump to later. The text _\* Note_ still shows when I use an anchor. (If you meant something else, could you please elaborate?)

Comment: @Fólkvangr I was hoping for a source based solution, but will accept configuring the Info as the last ditch. Further, I could not get your solution to work too -- see my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two primary Info readers: `info`, a stand-alone program
>   designed just to read Info files (see What is Info?)
>   and the `info` package in GNU Emacs, a general-purpose editor.

The stand-alone Info reader (greater or equal to version 6.0) may be configured to hide some information (related to *note* and menu items).

For more information, look at the [GNU Info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/), more precisely, look at chapter "[Manipulating Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Variables.html#Variables)" (`hide-note-references`) and look at chapter "Custom Key Bindings", section "[infokey format](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/infokey-format.html#infokey-format)" (last paragraphs).

```
prompt% info info hide-note-references
prompt% nano ~/.infokey
prompt% cat ~/.infokey
#var
hide-note-references=On
```

GNU Emacs (Info mode) may also be configured to hide some informations  (related to *note* and menu items), setting the variable `Info-hide-note-references`¹, in an Emacs initialization file (see GNU Emacs, chapter "[Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization.html#Customization)").

---

¹ <sub>Feature available in Texinfo, since version 4.8 (2005).</sub>

Comment: I could not get this to work on my info, which is in OSX (5.2). The manual also does not have a section on 'hide-note-references' inside `Custom Key BIndings`. I also tried `M-x set-variable` which does not seem to accept `hide-note-references`. Is this a new variable?

Comment: Ah, as I mentioned above, the Info version is 5.2 in OSX. So that is probably the reason.

Comment: Accepting this since it is closest to what I want.